# How do I print out an output from a specific index based upon 3 Lists (same position on list for all 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program where there are 3 Lists that will print out the name, wage, and total wage based upon their index location on the list.

The length of each variable cannot just be 6, so it should accommodate any input given (name/wage/hour list could as long as desired). Ignore data validation/formatting as we assume that the user will input the info correctly all the time for all the variables.

For example, I want my desired output to be (see index 0 in the list of the 3 variables in the code):

```
Sanchez worked 42.0 hours at $10.00 per hour, and earned $420.00
```

$420.00 -> (10.00*42.0)

Currently here is my code:

```
name = ['Sanchez', 'Ruiz', 'Weiss', 'Choi', 'Miller', 'Barnes']
wage = ['10.0', '18', '14.80', '15', '18', '15']
hours = [42.0, 41.5, 38.0, 21.5, 21.5, 22.5]


i = 0
for y in name:

    payOut = float(wage[i]) * float(hours[i])
    product = (name[i], wage[i], payOut)
    i += 1
    print(product)


empName = input("gimmie name: ") #no data validation neeeded

def target(i,empName):
    for x in i:
    if x == str(empName):
      empName = x #should return index of the empName
'''^^^ this is currently incorrect too as i believe it should return
the index location of the name, which I will use to print out the
final statement based upon the location of each respective variable 
list. (not sure if this works)'''



target(name,empName)
```

Comment: Please describe exactly how your code is failing. Provide full tracebacks for exceptions or explanations of how output differs from what you expect.

Comment: One approach would be to do some pre-processing and make a `{name: (wage, hours), ...}` dictionary

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method for the list. No need to iterate through everything.

```
emp_name = input("gimmie name: ") # Weiss

idx = name.index(emp_name) # 99% of the work is done right here.

print('{n} worked {h} hours at ${w:.2f} per hour, and earned ${p:.2f}'.format(
    n = name[idx], 
    h = hours[idx],
    w = float(wage[idx]), # Convert to float so you can show 2 decimals for currency
    p = float(wage[idx]) * hours[idx] # Calculate pay here
))

#Weiss worked 38.0 hours at $14.80 per hour, and earned $562.40
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [[Python 3]: **enumerate**(*iterable, start=0*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
names = ['Sanchez', 'Ruiz', 'Weiss', 'Choi', 'Miller', 'Barnes']
wages = ['10.0', '18', '14.80', '15', '18', '15']
hours = [42.0, 41.5, 38.0, 21.5, 21.5, 22.5]


def name_index(name_list, search_name):
    for index, item in enumerate(name_list):
        if item == search_name:
            return index
    return -1


emp_name = input("gimmie name: ")

idx = name_index(names, emp_name)
if idx == -1:
    print("Name {:s} not found".format(emp_name))
else:
    wage = float(wages[idx])
    hour = hours[idx]        
    print("{:s} worked {:.2f} hours at $ {:.2f} per hour earning $ {:.2f} ".format(names[idx], hour, wage, wage * hour))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your vectors have the same lenght, you case use  [range](https://snakify.org/pt/lessons/for_loop_range/).

```
for i in range(0,len(name),1):
    payOut = float(wage[i]) * float(hours[i])
    product = (name[i], wage[i], payOut)
    print(product)
```

Comment: No need to enter the step value for the range function if you're just going to specify the default.